# Efficient nearest neighbour search when list is growing?

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

I've been rewriting an old maze type thing I did for fun, though instead of being a maze it's a bit more abstract and shrinks down, so I can't just do a `if location in locations` search.

I've done a basic nearest neighbour search and have tried to optimise it a little, but it's still very slow, as in for every 10x more nodes, 1000x more calculations are needed (167 billion at 10,000 nodes, just for collision checking), so I don't think there's much more that can be done to this.

Here's the code slightly edited to work by itself, the nodes are normally a class and I iterate through each one and grab the size/location attribute (changed those to `node[0]` and `node[1]`). Imagine `node_list` has thousands of values.

```
dimensions = 3
dimensions_range = range(dimensions)
def collision_check(node_list, location, size, bounds=None):

    #Check new node is within bounds (if set)
    if bounds:
        for i in dimensions_range:
            if not bounds[0][i] + size <= location[i] <= bounds[1][i] - size:
                return True

    #Find if any nodes are overlapping
    for node in node_list:
        size_total = size + node[0]
        distance = [abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(location, node[1])]

        #Take these two lines out and the time taken doubles
        if max(distance) > size_total:
            continue

        #Square to do one half of pythagoras
        distance_total = sum(pow(i, 2) for i in distance)
        if distance_total < pow(size_total, 2):
            return True

    return False

node_list = [
[0.5, (0, 0, 0)],
[0.5, (0, 0, 1)]
]

new_size, new_loc = [0.5, (0, 0, 2)]
print collision_check(node_list, new_loc, new_size)
#No collision

new_size, new_loc = [0.6, (0, 0, 2)]
print collision_check(node_list, new_loc, new_size)
#Collision
```

I was thinking of a segment type idea, but as the nodes have dimensions, one point could potentially cross into 4 segments, meaning I'd have to do a `if any(i in existing_segments for i in current_segments)` check on every node, which sounds a lot like it could possibly end up slower. I've heard of KD trees and don't really understand them, but I'm guessing they wouldn't cope well with points being added as much as they are looked up.

This isn't anything important anyway, I'm just curious if there's a better way to do this that isn't ridiculously advanced.

Comment: you may find a quad tree algorithm useful for this.  In summary your maze would be divided into quadrants and each child node will have quadrants in it.  When you come to do collision detection you traverse from the top of the tree an evaluate "am I in this node" if yes traverse deeper, else move the next node.  Im on my phone so cannot provide a complete answer but here is a cool article on implementing quad trees: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves It is commonly used in 2D and 3D game development

Comment: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374 this resource also looks pretty good for implementing some code in a 2D environment

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a think about that approach, I'd have to figure out how to get it working in any number of dimensions which might be pretty hard. One thing though, my thing should be potentially infinite in range, but when I tried octrees before, I found going outside the initial range to be problematic, would you suggest in the case of that to just double the size and recalculate all the points?

Comment: In a 2D environment its not too hard as you don't need to deal with the Z plane, in the event you want to tackle 3D I have an implementation written in c++ here: https://github.com/alexmk92/ASEngine/blob/master/ASQuadTree.cpp its fairly well commented but theres a lot of erroneous code in there to handle vertex buffers etc (completely irrelevant for what you want).  You should be able to easily divide your maze into quadrants dynamically.  When the game loads you do your initial slice into 4 quadrants and then you decide how many child node you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing it in 3D software, but for example, I'd be able to easily do a 4D generation and link that with keyframes to make points appear and disappear, which is why I'd need to try make a dynamic octree thing that works with any dimensions you put in. How about expanding the tree if I go out of range though?

Comment: Very very messy implementation, but in case you're interested at all, I just managed to get mine working. It expands and recalculates the tree when needed, and can work in any number of dimensions. Each node stores its path, and to find close neighbours, I follow the path and use recursion to find all IDs at that level or below. It's considerably faster than before which is cool, it's just too intertwined currently to reuse elsewhere. Code at http://pastebin.com/PspS9Saf and example tree of 2k nodes in 3 dimensions at http://pastebin.com/gzkuJLNi :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, I'm glad you got it working.  Code looks really interesting.  Whats the runtime difference now in big O notation?

Comment: I imagine it's easily possible to do a better version than this, I was just winging it and got lucky it worked haha. Not sure if there's a special way of working out the big O thing, but here are some rough numbers (it can vary quite a bit, 8k and 16k I just ran once for obvious reasons) - 1000 nodes: 0.35/0.85 (40%), 2000: 0.85/3.75 (22.5%), 4000: 2.4/15 (16%), 8000: 6.0/60.0 (10%), 16000: 17.5/255 (7%) - so it seems to be around 3x faster normally but getting better as the generation gets larger :)

Comment: Quick question about your game, do you make one massive quadtree to store everything, or join multiple smaller quadtrees up (similar to how I presume elder scrolls does it)? That's one thing I've never really figured, since when I tried a voxel octree thing, it got significantly slower the larger it was.

Comment: In my game I use a single Quad Tree, however the map isn't too large so there aren't too many nodes to process (lets be honest modern hardware can deal with 20k nodes when computing on the GPU without much strain).  I'm fairly certain Elder Scrolls would stitch "zones" together so when the player leaves boundary "x" at position y it knows that they will be moving over to quad tree z.   But they are dealing with millions, maybe billions of nodes so it makes sense to divide the map up into multiple zones.